# Split a row from a table into two equal columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have this simple table and I need some help please:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 \\ \hline
Value  & 1       & 2       & 3       & 4       & 5       & 6       \\       \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Total}                                        \\     \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Val1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Val2}             \\    \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And looks like this :
[image]

How can I make the columns in the row with **val1** and **val2** equal width?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. I've made your fragment into a compilable document. If that doesn't match your document please edit the question accordingly. As an aside, it's really bad practice to use `\resizebox` to change the size of the table. To get a table the width of the line use `tabularx`. If the table is too large, figure out ways to split it, display it sideways, or reduce the width of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any additional package and (almost) no change to your existing table (I only reduced your code to the `tabular` and changed the relevant line):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
         & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1  \\
  \hline
  Value  & 1       & 2       & 3       & 4       & 5       & 6        \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Total}                                         \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{\hfill Val1\hfill\vline\hfill Val2\hfill\null} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 But to the extent that this doesn't capture what the `\resizebox` code was doing in the OPs question, it may not be what they want.

Comment: @AlanMunn but since you added an answer which deals with the macro-which-shall-not-be-used-on-tables's task I felt that I'd have to do it without `tabularx` just for the sake of it. And I didn't feel like doing the calculation of the available width for equal-spaced cells myself :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fix my problem using your example. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do this: use the `tabularx` to make the table have equally spaced columns for the whole width of the table, and then embed a second table inside for the evenly spaced columns at the bottom.

I've used the `array` package to define a centred `X` column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
   & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 & Zone A1 \\ \hline
Value  & 1       & 2       & 3       & 4       & 5       & 6       \\       \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Total}                                        \\     \hline
\multicolumn{7}{|@{}c@{}|}{\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{C|C}Val1 & Val2 \end{tabularx}}       \\    \hline
\end{tabularx}%

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

As I mentioned in the comments, it's generally bad practice to use `\resizebox` to change a table size, since it changes the font size of the document.  So using `tabularx` allows you to specify the width of the table directly.  Vertical lines in tables are also usually not necessary, so you might also want to look at using the `booktabs` package instead and not using any vertical lines. Of course they are sometimes appropriate, so I have left your example as is in my answer.

[image: output of code]

Comment: No need to load `array` yourself, it's required by `tabularx` anyway.

Comment: @Skillmon I prefer to load package dependencies explicitly in answers like this since the documentation for `array` is separate from that of `tabularx`.

Comment: Very good point.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried to run your code, but it failed (no error, but misalignments). For me, the line which shall be split should be `\multicolumn{7}{|@{}C@{}|}{\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{C|C}Val1 & Val2 \end{tabularx}} \\\hline` (the misalignment is noticeable in your uploaded picture).

Comment: @Skillmon You're absolutely right. Thanks. I've fixed the code.